# How can I redefine '+' inside of a closure?

Tags: r, closures

First of all, I know that this is stupid and never should be done in practice. I also know that even when doing it in practice, you ought to do it with OOP. I'm just doing it to prove a point.

I want to redefine `'+'`. I want

```
'+' <- function(x, y) x + y + 2
```

to work. Allowing for code like

```
2 + 2
```

to return `6`.

Currently, it doesn't work because it causes an infinite recursion. To solve this, I want to use a closure, but I'm at a loss as to how. I obviously want something like:

```
SillyPlusGenerator <- function() {'+' <- function(x, y) x + y + 2}
```

but that doesn't give me a way to evaluate `2 + 2` in an environment where `+` is redefined and it doesn't tell `SillyPlusGenerator` to look up `+` in the parent environment. I know that I could play around with `eval` and use environments directly, but I feel sure that closures are all that I need.

What step have I missed?

Comment: ughh ... '+' <- function(x, y) (base::`+`)((base::`+`)(x, y), 2) or redefine `+` in the function ... '+' <- function(x, y) { "+" = base::`+` ; x + y + 2}

Comment: @user20650 Yep, that's all that I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Should clarify:  due to SO's markdown, the "`" char got eaten  in @user20650 's comment.  You need to type     "base::\`+\`"

Comment: In SO markdown within markdown backquotes to show a backquote escape it by prefacing it with a backslash.

Comment: `\`+\` <- function(x, y) { \`+\` = base::\`+\` ; x + y + 2}` Thanks @G.Grothendieck ive got it

Comment: Someone please post an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer shows a couple of quick ways "*To solve this*", but does not attempt to use closures.

To avoid the infinite recursion, you can:

- Call the normal base R `` `+` `` function explicitly within the custom function (noting that `` `+` `` can be called as you would with a standard function e.g. `` `+`(2,2) ``).

```
`+` <- function(x, y) (base::`+`)((base::`+`)(x, y), 2) 

# and a variation of:
`+` <- function(x, y) Reduce(base::`+`, c(x, y, 2))
```

- Redefine the `` `+` `` function within the custom function

```
`+` <- function(x, y) { `+` = base::`+` ; x + y + 2}
```